# How can i create my own hook in drupal6?

Tags: php, drupal

How does drupal create its own hook. Similarly i want a customized hook for myself. How am I to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are looking for [module_invoke_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/6)

Some useful links to start with:

- [Creating hooks for your Drupal modules](http://web.archive.org/web/20101227170201/http://himerus.com/blog/himerus/creating-hooks-your-drupal-modules)
- [How hooks are invoked with module_invoke_all()](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3SoAYtdcdo)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hook that passes a parameter by reference, and you can not use drupal_alter (for example a presave hook that passes in more than one argument) you can use module_implements.

This way a module could implement it as modulename_foo_presave instead of modulename_presave_alter.  It is good for when you you want to let modules alter something at multiple points in its life cycle.

For an example in drupal core checkout the code for the node_validate (drupal 7).

```
foreach (module_implements('node_validate') as $module) {
  $function = $module . '_node_validate';
  $function($node, $form, $form_state);
}
```

from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_validate/7

The same approach works in Drupal 6 if you want to create hook that can be implemented in this way.